# Making a windows metro control draggable

Tags: user-controls, drag-and-drop, microsoft-metro

I want to make a metro user control draggable. The user should be able to drag it and drop it on other controls, causing things to happen. How do I implement this functionality?

The only method I've discovered that works is using the GridView and ListView controls. They have a 'CanDragItems' property which, when true, means any item in the view can be dragged and dropped. I tried wrapping my control in a gridview or listview but they interfere with the layout in [ways I don't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHnIW.png).

I'd prefer not to emulate functionality provided by the OS. I could do it, by using the raw mouse/tap events, but it wouldn't properly respect system settings like the size of the dead zone preventing accidental dragging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just emulating the functionality by watching mouse events. I ask the control being dragged for a 'doppleganger' copy that looks the same but has no functionality, place it on the top-level grid, and adjust its render transform to move it.

However, note that if my requirements had been slightly different I might have been able to use the *manipulation* mode/events to do what I wanted. They're particularly nice because they have inertia built-in, but they're a bit pickier about focus and I didn't manage to cross parent control boundaries with it.

Answer (score 0):

what I would say is that you have to create an attach property on the Grid and draw an adorner that would hook up to the MouseDown/MouseUp events, from there you set the Grid.Column's Width/Grid.Row's Height. That would make the Grid draggable.

I won't suggest to use the built in property ShowGridLines as this is only used for debugging. You can try using Grid Splitters if you want and less code.

More on attached properties are found here [Attach Properties](http://www.wpftutorial.net/AttachedProperties.html)